# How to create Git Hooks without doing it on the repo server

Tags: git

I am trying to setup some hooks in git so I did the following:

```
git clone git@git:project
cd project/.git/hooks
vi post-receive
```

I then added my code to the post-receive file.  I then commited the project and did a push but I dont see my hook on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  Commit access to the code the repo's managing isn't the same thing, at all, as administrative control over the repo.  For that, you need direct access on the system hosting it (or some form of handrolled automated delegation, perhaps in the form of git hooks ...).

Comment: So will the hook run if I do it on my local repo just for me?

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to chmod +x it.

Answer (score 0):

The `.git` directory stores data about the repository.  Files in this directory are **not** tracked by Git, but rather are used to store data about the files that *are* tracked by Git.

Therefore, the `.git/hooks` directory is not shared between repositories and is not versioned.  You need to make the changes on the server itself.

Comment: so how can I setup a hook without having server access

Comment: so should the hook run if I do it on my local repo just for me?

Comment: @SJS Yes, but the hooks will run at a different time.  The post-receive hook is executed after someone has pushed to your repository (and possibly when you pull from someone else's, I don't remember).  If nobody ever pushes to your local repository then this hook won't be executed.